# How to remove city as a required field at checkout page in magento 1.9.3.6?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.0.1, ce-1.9.1.0, magento1.9.3

I want to remove required field from city and make it non required field at checkout page. how can i implement this?

[image]

Comment: Why would "city" not be required? Isnt it a very useful field for invoice, shipping... Its part of the address, is there really a usecase where one have no city?

Comment: @roman204 - there is some error in city field, city value does not save in customer address, it show error when place order again - city is a required field.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `city` as a required field from checkout page by customizing template file of billing & shipping address form.

In `rwd` theme of default Magento 1.9.3.6 you can customize below code in both template files.

**For Billing Address form:** `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

Replace below code

```
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />
</div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:city"><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text" id="billing:city" />
</div>
</div>
```

**For Shipping Address form:** `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

Replace below code

```
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="shipping[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="shipping:city" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
</div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:city"><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="shipping[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text" id="shipping:city" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
</div>
</div>
```

I hope this will useful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove the required class from following files in your theme folder.

```
checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

<!--<label for="shipping:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('city') ?></label>-->
<label for="shipping:city"><?php echo $this->__('city') ?></label>
```

also remove classes from input field as-well

```
<?php //echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>
```

2- copy this core class to your local and remove following lines
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

```
/*if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getcity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
  $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the city number.'));
}*/
```

3- Change the attribute is_required in DB

```
update eav_attribute set is_required=0 where attribute_code='city';
```

Note: step three is a dirty hack, correct way would be creating an setup file in your custom extension.